# creating a web app which allows a member registers other members

Tags: php, mysql

am in a tight end, I was contracted to create a PHP web application that allows one to register and the user can then register 5 more others, the other users he registered can also register 5 members each.

I am expected to create the database to save the users a particular member registered in array, whereby I will list them out in table form,

The confusing part is

1. how to factor out the database structure so that it can save the five users, then when queried list them out (am confused as to save them in array or a separate table). But I'd prefer saving in array
2. any other user who gets registered by any of the 5 registered, would be linked to the main Referee and all of them would be counted and the whole process stops as the user registers 5 members and the 5 members also register 5 users each to his/her account make it 25 total for each account

It could be illustrated as

```
1. Parent - 5 children -
```

then the 5 children bears 5 children each, the parent would acknowledge both his children and his grandchildren, once the children and grandchildren gets to 25 in number, the reproductive cycle ends for the parent, his children can carry on to make theirs 25 also

I have made the database but I needed some guidelines to build it successfully as I have 3 days to complete this part.

```
public function userTable()
{
    $qry = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    user_id         INT(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    username        VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    password        VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    referralIDs             varchar(500) NOT NULL,
    totalRefers        VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL ,
    userIDhash          varchar(30) not null,
    date                date,
    time                varchar(20) not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    )TYPE=INNODB";
$result = $this->qry($qry);
    return;
}

    public function ReferralTable()
{
    $qry = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Refers(
    user_id         INT(50) NOT NULL, 
    usersRegistered        VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL,
    referby             int(50) not null
    )TYPE=INNODB";
$result = $this->qry($qry);
    return;
}
```

I will prefer to work with only one table that will save my children in an array delimited by "," and then I can start off there
am confused as how to save it, and retrieve the children's ID one after the other with which I can use to query for the grandchildren

Hope am not confusing any one?? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want us to do? Complete your work? Teach you database design? Tell you how to join array elements to a comma-delimited string?

Answer (score 1):

why would you need to use an array?
it's a simple one to many relation... just create a table which holds this relation, or heck - a field in user table...

here is an example for the two table example...

user table

```
id | email | name | whatever
1    a@b.c   jon
2    j@b.c   mel
```

user_registered

```
register_id | registree_id
    1             null
    2              1
```

an example for one table

```
id | email | name | whatever | ref_user_id
1     a@b.c   jon                NULL
2     j@b.c   mel                  1
3     f@b.c   al                   1
```

than you can get all the users that 1 registered:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE ref_user_id = 1
```

or get the amount of people that 1 registered

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE ref_user_id = 1
```

in both cases, user with id of 1, registered first (not refered), and he registered user #2

Comment: thanks for the insight, but in this case now also, any other user registered by 2 (total of 5) should be linked with user 1, then when am querying user 1 should have total of 10(5 his + 5 from user 2), in this case now he would have registered 5 users, 2 3 4 5 6, 2 = 5, 3 = 5, 4 = 5, 5 = 5, 6 = 5, then user 1 would have total of 25 to his account, I would be grateful if you can help me sort it out

Comment: I would strongly recommend to not worry about optimization right now and just run 6 queries. else, you could do something like this: SELECT * FROM user WHERE ref_user_id = (SELECT id FROM user WHERE ref_user_id = null) this will fetch all the 1st generation children. aside from that - because SQL has problem displaying tree structure (which is what you want) I'd recommend reading on binary trees in sql, there are alot of examples which you can get from google.